# How to Respond to "Why is this of interest?"

Tags: discussion

What's the best way to answer the question "Why is this of interest?" [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464369/how-to-compute-the-cost-of-querying-an-additional-table-using-left-join#comment32393408_21464369) to a question posed to StackOverflow? It seems what is of interest to one person may not be of interest to another. A question is always of interest to the one posing the question. I ask questions daily as part of my work as a software engineer.  I come to StackOverflow to do research, pose questions to my peers.

The question "Why is this of interest?" sounds like a judgement to me. It tips me off that someone has already formed a negative opinion of my question and deems it of no particular  value. Why not move on then to other questions? Why comment?

Comment: I would not respond at all. Flag as *Not constructive*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the question.

Sometimes, such comments, however rude(-ish), can help uncover an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

It may be worth to ignore the curtness, and answer politely, just in case the question's relevance may not be as obvious to others as it is to you.

In your specific case, the comment's author doesn't seem to believe that dealing with the performance differences you show has any real-world relevance. That seems like a fair question to ask, even though it may not be true.

Comment: It would have been nice if the commenter had asked an actual question.   He didn't say what "this" meant, didn't qualify the term "interest," and didn't provide any helpful guidance, so the comment really doesn't have much veracity.  Had I been the one to ask the question, I would have ignored the comment.

Comment: @Robert I disagree.  It could have been more verbose - but the question is still a fair one to ask: "Why do you want to know this i the first place?" and note that the guy who made the comment seems to be a respected voice in his field. If I were the question asker, I'd be *dying* to know what this guy thinks about my approach.

Comment: Why does he need to know *that?*

Comment: @Robert  because it could be interpreted as a pointless micro-optimization question. Not saying it really is one - the OP sounds too knowledgeable for that. But there are thousands of "what is more efficient, x or y?" questions on SO, the answer to most of them being "it doesn't matter."

Comment: Then he should say "Is this micro-optimization?  If it is, it probably doesn't matter."  At least then, we could have understood what the hell he was asking.

Comment: @Robert agreed. ---

Comment: That's a good point (about uncovering a potential XY problem).  In this case, my manager asked me to do some research.  I think product management was concerned that a JOIN would adversely impact query run times, but these PostgreSQL queries generally run so fast on  tables of reasonable size (when written properly) that I do not know that it makes much difference.  For me the challenge was in finding and reporting results in a statistically meaningful way.

Comment: My original SO question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464369/how-to-compute-the-cost-of-querying-an-additional-table-using-left-join

Comment: I'm with Pekka here (and the commenter) @Michael. You're asking completely the wrong question. You're having problems proving differences because, in your situation, there might be minimal difference. However, as the (now first) commenter pointed out (more politely than I'm going to) 18s to join 500 rows is dog slow - I would be upset if that took more than a few ms. You're manager's asked you to concentrate on completely the wrong thing and you should be posting another question with your table DDL, the explain plan, and the query asking for help rather than trying to nibble around the edges.